# npm rm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

```
$ npm rm gulp -g
```

> npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Please do not put "Resolved" in the title - instead you write an answer and then mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
# workmachine@HH-00 MINGW64 /c/HTML5/app (dev)
$ npm rm gulp -g
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

# workmachine@HH-00 MINGW64 /c/HTML5/app (dev)
$ npm install --global npm

$ npm rm gulp -g
removed 251 packages in 4.554s
```